# How to loop through a percentage investment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on this simple task where a financial advisor suggests to invest in a stock fund that is guaranteed to increase by 3 percent over the next five years.

Here's my code:

```
while True:
    investment = float(input('Enter your initial investment: '))
    if 1000 <= investment <= 100000:
        break
    else:
        print("Investment must be between $1,000 and $100,000")


#Annual interest rate 
apr = 3 / 100
amount = investment

for yr in range(5):
    amount = (amount) * (1. + apr)
    print('After {:>2d} year{} you have:   $ {:>10.2f}'.format(yr, 's,' if yr > 1 else ', ', amount))
```

Comment: What is `enumerate(1)`? Is should case `Error`

Comment: `for yr in range(5)`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov I just got rid of enumerate

Comment: What is the code doing that you don't expect?  With a quick glance at it, the only problem I can see is that ranges are 0 based by default.  You may want to change your range to `range(1,6)` which will go from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it. The only problem is that `apr` is runing integer math. Use floating point numbers instead, so `apr` does not round to zero:

```
apr = 3.0 / 100.0
```

By changing that line your program will probably work

This is the whole code changes (as requested in comments):

```
while True:
    investment = float(input('Enter your initial investment: '))
    if 1000 <= investment <= 100000:
        break
    else:
        print("Investment must be between $1,000 and $100,000")


#Annual interest rate 
apr = 3.0 / 100.0
amount = investment

for yr in range(5):
    amount = (amount) * (1. + apr)
    print('After {:>2d} year{} you have:   $ {:>10.2f}'.format(yr, 's,' if yr > 1 else ', ', amount))
```

The output I get is:

```
Enter your initial investment: 1002 
After  0 year,  you have:   $    1032.06
After  1 year,  you have:   $    1063.02
After  2 years, you have:   $    1094.91
After  3 years, you have:   $    1127.76
After  4 years, you have:   $    1161.59
```

Comment: I just tried it without success. Can you try it please?

Comment: I did. After running with that change this is the output I get `Enter your initial investment: 1002 
After  0 year,  you have:   $    1032.06
After  1 year,  you have:   $    1063.02`. What version of python are you running in?

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code on here please? Thanks!

Comment: progx: You need to be more specific than "without success". Exactly what goes wrong? Because Jorge Torres' suggestion is sufficient. I ran this in Python 2, whlie only modifying the print syntax from the Python 3 syntax you are using.

Comment: @progx In case that this is relevant, this is my test platform: `Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux`. I copied and pasted the code as you requested. I also posted an example of the output I get. I hope this helps

Comment: With Python 2.X, print is not a function, so it's arguments are not put inside a parenthesis. Just do "print argument" rather than "print(argument)".

Comment: Also tested in python 3 `Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux` with the same (fixed) results. Is there a chance that you could be running an old copy progx? If not, you migth want to install a different version of python and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: @JorgeTorres my bad sorry, I had some extra useless code on my editor. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson I guess it was just me having extra code on my editor. Thanks anyway! I fixed my issue

Comment: @JorgeTorres any ideas on how I can change my code so it takes different investments and not just one (1 to 5 investments) and do the same calculation for each investment? Thanks in advanced

Comment: I would wrap all the code you have outside the while in a function, such function cuuld take as parameters the percentage and the investment. The in your main code, you run a loop `N` times (for instace five as you suggest) asking for the parameters and pasisng them to the function. That way you can run as many times as you want, and you can even as how many investments `N` will the user input.

Comment: @JorgeTorres  would you mind adding some of the code you're saying and then I can finish it myself please, so I can see what you're talking about? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103176/discussion-between-jorge-torres-and-progx).

Answer (score 0):

```
new_a=1000
yi = .03
for yr in range(1,6):
    new_a = new_a+new_a*yi
    print('After {:>2d} year{} you have:   $ {}'.format(yr, 's,' , new_a))
```